# Statements equivalent to strongly polynomial time linear programming

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, time-complexity, reductions, big-list, computing-over-reals

Say a problem is SPT iff it admits an [SPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Strongly_and_weakly_polynomial_time) algorithm. What statements of interest are known to be equivalent to "[LP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) is SPT"? Examples:

- "[linear feasibility solving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_inequality#Systems_of_linear_inequalities) is SPT" (due to the [strong duality theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_linear_program#Strong_duality))
- "solving [zero-sum games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-sum_game) is SPT" (see [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00182-012-0328-8))

Are there others? I'd be especially interested in knowing if there are any examples that are purely "discrete" or "combinatorial" in flavor, e.g. "X is [complexity class]" (not SPT and without reference to real numbers).

Counterexamples:

- [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.11587) says "it is open whether 2-[commodity flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-commodity_flow_problem) and
  linear programming are equivalent in strongly polynomial time".